# Результаты поиска через searchControl отформатировать возможно ли..?

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Для данного простого примера можно ли отформатировать отображение найденных объектов на карте через балуны аналогично Placemark или другим способом? Хотелось бы поменять графический значок объектов на карте (для всех сразу) и вписать в значки свой текст (одинаковый для всех объектов).

```
function init() {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.74, 37.58],
        zoomф: 13,
        controls: []
    });

    var searchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
        options: {
            provider: 'yandex#search',
            size:'small'
        }
    });

    myMap.controls.add(searchControl);

    searchControl.search('Шоколадница');
}

ymaps.ready(init);
```

Answer (score 1):

Для провайдера provider: 'yandex#search' так сделать нельзя.

Для провайдера "по-умолчанию" есть пример https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_search_results

Comment: А если использовать координаты найденных объектов через 'yandex#search' и по ним построить метки ymaps.Placemark с пользовательскими балунами, это будет легальное использование api?

Comment: Вряд ли, по таким тонкостям лучше задать вопрос в техподдержку Яндекса.